18650 battery holder corrosion
I'm using a Keystone Electronics 18650 battery holder #1043, link below. The connection between the cell terminals and the battery holder seems to have what I think are slight corrosion issues. I take out the battery, wipe everything clean and it works for a few months. After a few months, the corrosion builds up and it creates a poor connection again. It worked fine for the first 2.5 years but now I seem to be getting this problem every few months.
Any ideas on a retrofit I can do to create better terminal connections? I guess I could solder some foil to the battery holder spring connections before putting the battery in, but I'm just asking in case anyone has any ideas/experience.
Also, are there any other battery holders you would recommend I should be using in future designs?
https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Keystone-Electronics/1043?qs=%2F7TOpeL5Mz6j%2FnxeOA1rsg%3D%3D

What environment is the battery holder being used in? For example, on a marine vessel?

Thanks, it's in a Hammond Enclosure, stationary in a garden in the UK and there is a vented cable gland. I have never found any water or condensation inside the enclosure in the 3.5 years it has been deployed.

I suppose you could swap the holder for a new one (the current one appears to be done with if it keeps going dodgy)  and liberally apply some grease of any sort you happen to have (maybe you've got some car battery terminal grease that will never be used up in the next umpty years) over the terminals in the hope it prevents corrosion. If it then corrodes in the next few years, perhaps look to a different grease.

If you want reliability, these batteries should not be used with battery holders to begin with.
These batteries are available with solder tabs where you can solder wires directly, and also with pre-installed wires where you can put your own connector, and also these are available with wires and connectors preinstalled.

Thanks for the reply, I may do this in the next design revision

The materials seem reasonable enough- stainless steel,  plated with a barrier layer of nickel and tin on top.
I think you'd have to do a bit more analysis. If the application has a lot of vibration it's possible the plating has worn off and you're up against the stainless steel's chromium oxide layer, which is a rather good insulator. Especially possible if the pressure of the holder is low. There is a lot of variation between holders, some grip like there's no tomorrow. Part of that is probably that the protected cells measure 67.4mm rather than 65mm.
On the other hand, if the application is completely stationary, then it's possible something chemical in the environment is causing corrosion. In that, and pretty much in that case only, you could look at Keystone's sister product the gold-plated 1042/1042P. The gold flash is extremely thin, almost not there.

Thanks for the reply, I agree I should do some more analysis. It is a stationary application so maybe I will look to the gold-plated version. Thank you for letting me know the materials seem reasonable, it is good to know.
